# How to: *.csv -->line -->someArray-->modification

Tags: c#, arrays, string, winforms

Now try to create some code, that take one string from **CSV** file and compare it with some criteria. If this string pass criteria than, divide it in to 4 pieces - put each pieces in array, than take some new values from `TextBox` and change it.

Currently I'm on point, when need to divide selected string. Prepare some code, but instead of getting array with divided pieces get only `System.string[]`

Code

```
 try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite); 
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs); //open file for reading
            string[] line = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                                             StringSplitOptions.None); //read file to the end an divide it 
            sr.Close(); //close stream
            foreach (var l in line) //check each line for criteria
            {
                if (l.Contains(dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + eventNameUpdateTextBox.Text.ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string[] temp = { "", "", "", "", };// i always have just 4 part of string
                        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
                        {
                            updatedTtextBox.Text = temp[i] = l.Split(',').ToString(); //try to divide it
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

but result -

[image: debug]

where i'm make mistake?

Comment: it's like `"26 august 2013 y., Name, 10:00, 11:00, Description"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call of `l.Split(',')` produces an array of `string`s, i.e. a `String[]`. Calling `ToString()` on such an array produces `"System.String[]"` - the value that you see in the output.

You need to split ahead of the loop, and pick an element from the split as you advance through the indexes, then do whatever you need to do with each part. If all you want is placing the parts into individual elements of the `temp` array, perhaps limiting the number of items to `4`, then `l.Split(',').Take(4).ToArray()` should be sufficient.

It is strange that you are replacing `updatedTtextBox.Text` four times as you go through the loop. Taking a guess at what you are trying to accomplish, here is what you could try doing:

```
string[] temp = l.Split(',').Take(4).ToArray();
// For display purposes, you can join the data back with a different separator:
updatedTtextBox.Text = string.Join("|", temp);
```

Comment: try - you are right! I replace 4 times `updatedTtextBox.Text` - just try to see at any line - temporary add this line - forget to delete

Comment: also don't know about `Take()` - usefull thing